# Java - How to split an ArrayList input into Date and String and then compare?

Tags: java, date, arraylist

I've searched multiple posts and can't find something specific for my needs.

### ** The goal**

I need to take a user input in the form of Date and then a String description and **store it in an Arraylist**.
i.e 10 Nov 2021, Clean my room
I want my date to be in D MMM YYYY format 
Once this is stored in the arraylist, I need to be able to search the arraylist of tasks for the ***current date***
If my arraylist contains a task for 11 Nov 2021 and current date/local machine date is 11 Nov 2021, I need to print the task for today , else print out that no tasks exist for the current date.

Here is a snippet of what I've tried so far

```
public class TestClass {
    
    public static void main(String[]args){
 
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));         
      try{
          System.out.println("Enter : ");  
   // sample string   
        String str = br.readLine();              
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
        System.out.println("--------------");
        System.out.println(list);
      }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
      
}
  
}
```

Here is an output

```
Enter : 
10 jan 2020, clean room
--------------
[10 jan 2020,  clean room]
```

I'm not sure how to proceed next, thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest creating a class to store each date and string, maybe named `Task` or something else appropriate. Then you can create an array list of instances of the class.

Comment: Then the next step is to write a method where you can search the list of tasks for one on a certain day.

Comment: Could you provide a code example ?

Comment: I’m afraid that we are awaiting a bit more effort on your part. The web is filled with code examples. You will find many examples of a model class/POJO class that you can use as inspiration for your `Task` class. You will find many examples of how to split a string at the first comma (or other predefined character). Many examples of how to parse a date string into a `LocalDate` (only avoid example using the troublesome and long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` classes).

Comment: If any of that turns out not to be as trivial as it sounds (which is likely to be the case), please show us your attempt in a new question, and we will be here to help, promise. Feel free to drop a link to your new question in a comment here.

Comment: @mrwahl I suggest you start by reading about classes and how to create instances.

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Comment: @BasilBourque Agree, obviously. The OP already reported: *I've searched multiple posts and can't find something specific for my needs.* So if we can give them something more specific about what to search for or how to search, I think it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you:

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));         
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM yyyy");  
        List<Task> tasks=new ArrayList<Task>();       
        while (true) {
           try{
               System.out.println("Enter : ");  
               String str = br.readLine();
               Task task= new Task(str.split(",")[0],str.split(",")[1]);
               tasks.add(task);
               System.out.println("--------------");
               System.out.println(task.toString());
               System.out.println("--------------");
               System.out.println("Tasks for today");
               LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();  
               String currentDateStr=dtf.format(now);
               System.out.println(getTasksByDate(tasks,currentDateStr));
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("Enter a valid input");
            }   
        }
         
 }
 public static List<Task> getTasksByDate(List<Task> tasks,String date ){
     List<Task> res=new ArrayList<Task>(); 
     for(int i=0;i<tasks.size();i++) {
         if(tasks.get(i).getDate().equals(date)) {
             res.add(tasks.get(i));
         }
     }
     return res;
 }
}
//Task.java
public class Task {
    private String date;
    private String subject;
    public Task(String date,String subject) {
        this.date=date;
        this.subject=subject;
    }
    public String getSubject() {
        return this.subject;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return this.date + ":" +this.subject ;
    }
}
```

Comment: **Don't use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`.**

Comment: And you should properly model a task, instead of using an array. Use objects.

Comment: I have taken your comments into account.

Comment: Much better. :)

Comment: @ZinedineBenkhider Thank your for the above snippet, it's working well for me.

Comment: Line `Task task= new Task(str.split(",")[0],str.split(",")[1]);`
is giving error "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"
@ZinedineBenkhider

Comment: @mrwahl You must create new file for Task class. Don't make it in the main class. Please Don't forget to validate my answer if it work .

Comment: It’s not really good. In `Task` the date should be a `LocalDate`, not a `String`. Upper case `YYYY` in the format pattern string is wrong, you need lower case `uuuu` or `yyyy`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Year can be writed with Upper case or with Lower case. Task date is String to avoid converting the input value to LocalDate, and converting LocalDate to string when we display it.

Comment: @ZinedineBenkhider You are quite [incorrect about `Y` and `y`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) being the same in a date-time parser. So the code in this Answer may return incorrect results, thus my down-vote.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thank you very much for this explanation.

Comment: Code fixed, so I removed my down-vote.